# Several objects from another level appearing in a level that they shouldn't?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, levels

I created a project in Unreal, Top Down Character.

**By default, the scene looks like this:**

[image]

I thought of creating a main menu to take the player to the other scenes of the project I intend to do. For that I created an empty level.

**See below:**

[image]

- I created the "Level_Menu", "BP_Menu_Widget" and "BP_Menu_ADM".
- Notice that in the hierarchy I just added the "BP_Menu_ADM".

**At first, visually, everything looks normal. I just created a text with the name of the project:**

[image]

**The problem is when I look at the hierarchy:**

[image]

A huge amount of objects appear. Objects that I have no idea why they appear. I imagine it has something to do with the fact that the project is initially a default project (top down) from Unreal itself.

**An important detail is that the project is not purely blueprint, I created it exactly like this:**

[image]

[image]

Before coming here (as usual), I tried to research something like this, even in English (which is not the language I speak). But I didn't find anything related (I probably don't know how to use the right terms).

I changed the gamemode, I set everything to "none", I got to the point of opening a script called "world.h", but when I went to play with it to see what happened, Visual Studio warned that it was a read-only file.

Then I finally recognized that I needed help. I would like someone to help me understand what is happening and how to solve it, without necessarily creating a project from scratch. I will only use this option as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched further and found the answer on the Unreal forum.

**Link of question (question and answer from 'saldavonschwartz'):**

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/how-to-create-a-truly-blank-empty-project/377987/2

In short, Unreal by default will always create some objects that have to be present in every scene.

**To solve the problem, just create a new 'Game Mode Base':**

[image]

**Go to the 'World Settings' window:**

[image]

**Change the 'GameMode Overrides' option (by default it will be 'none'), selecting the game mode you created:**

[image]

Even so, when you press play, several objects will be created (they are necessary and mandatory, in the link I sent above, it explains a little about). But the project's default player will not be.